# Shooting with a shotgun 2D Top-down Shooter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm trying to make shooting with a shotgun, I have already made shooting with one bullet. Code:

```
            Vector2 shootingDirection = new Vector2(joystick.Horizontal, joystick.Vertical);
            shootingDirection.Normalize();           
            if (shootingDirection != new Vector2(0, 0))
            {
                if(isShotGun) ShotGunShoot(shootingDirection);
                GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, crossHair.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                bullet.transform.Rotate(0.0f, 0.0f, Mathf.Atan2(shootingDirection.y, shootingDirection.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);
                bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(shootingDirection * 10f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            }

        }
```

But I'm just trying to create two other bullets with a slight deviation from the main one, so that it looks like a fraction, but it does not work correctly. Code:

```
    private void ShotGunShoot(Vector2 dir)
    {
        GameObject shotGun = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, crossHair.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        shotGun.transform.Rotate(0.0f, 0.0f, Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 30f);
        shotGun.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce((dir + new Vector2(-.3f, 0f)) * 10f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
   
        shotGun = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, crossHair.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        shotGun.transform.Rotate(0.0f, 0.0f, Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + 30f);
        shotGun.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce((dir+ new Vector2(.3f, 0f)) * 10f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
```

As it should be

[image]

Here it is now

[image]

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the rotation. You can simply set the direction (from your image I can see that your bullet has to fly towards its right vector) like e.g.

```
shotgun.transform.right = dir;
shotgun.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 30);
```

For the add force: This uses world space directions.

You always pass in the direction and add the additional offset in world space. So that additional offset goes always in X axis direction regardless in which direction you shoot.

Rather take the direction into account by using the local force [`Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce.html)

```
shotGun.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForceRelative((shotgun.transform.right + new Vector2(0f, 0.3f)).normalized * 10f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

This now uses the bullets right direction and additionally uses an offset of `0.3` along its **local** Y axis.

---

Btw: If you give your prefab the correct type

```
public Rigidbody bulletPrefab;
```

you can skip the `GetComponent<Rigidbody>` calls.